# Show all of sum and count without using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to Retrieve customer names, total orders (how many time they order the products) and the total amount they're spent in the lifetime. Run a single query WITHOUT `Join`, `group by`, `having` operators. Show only customers who have at least one order.

Here is my database

```
Customer-    CustomerID| CustomerName   SalesOrder- SalesOrderID | CustomerID | SaleTotal
             100000    |  John                        1001       |   100000   |  2000
             200000    |  Jane                        1002       |   100000   |  3000  
             300000    |  Sean                        1003       |   200000   |  5000
```

When I query

```
SELECT CustomerName,count(*) AS Total_Orders,sum(SaleTotal) AS SaleTotal                           
FROM Customer C,SalesOrderHeader SH WHERE C.CustomerID=SH.CustomerID;
```

It show only one row.
The answer that I want is

```
CustomerName | Total_Orders | SaleTotal
John            2               5000
Jane            1               5000
```

I just new on mysql.
So does anyone here know how to do this?

Comment: Where such restrictions are taken from?

Comment: @Akina I just want to know that is it possible to query like this

Comment: Without Join and group by, this result cannot be achieved

Comment: Quote: "When I query `... FROM Customer C,SalesOrderHeader SH ...`". You shouldn't. This join syntax is a relict of the 1980s, i.e. before explicit joins got invented. That's thirty years ago. Use proper joins:  `FROM customer c INNER JOIN salesorderheader sh ON sh.customerid = c.customerid`.

Comment: Besides, your query is invalid. A good DBMS should raise an error, when you `SELECT CustomerName` in this aggregation query without `GROUP BY CustomerName`, because there ain't no one single `CustomerName` matching the criteria. You seem to be running an old version of MySQL. Make sure you set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to prevent you from writing incorrect queries. Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to do this without `join`s and `group by`, then the simplest approach is to use correlated subqueries:

```
select *
from (
    select
        c.customerName,
        (
            select count(*) 
            from salesOrder so 
            where so.customerID = c.customerID
        ) totalOrders,
        (
            select sum(salesTotal) 
            from salesOrder so 
            where so.customerID = c.customerID
        ) saleTotal
    from customer c
) t
where totalOrders > 0
```

Note that this query is clearly suboptimal - because it scans the `salesOrder` table twice, while a single scan would suffice. A better way to write this would be:

```
select c.customerName, count(*) totalOrders, sum(salesTotal) saleTotal
from customer c
inner join saleOrder so on so.customerID = c.customerID
group by c.customerID, c.customerName
```

There is no need for a `having` clause here - the `inner join` filters out customers that have no order already.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation . . . and proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT CustomerName, COUNT(*) AS Total_Orders, SUM(SaleTotal) AS SaleTotal                           
FROM Customer C JOIN
     SalesOrderHeader SH 
     ON C.CustomerID = SH.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerName;
```

Your query would fail in almost any database -- including newer versions of MySQL.  You have mixed aggregated columns and unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`. The unaggregated ones should be in a `GROUP BY`.

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: OP specified, that he doesnt want join and group by to be used in the query

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below query. You cannot achieve it without `join` and `group by`

```
SELECT CustomerName,count(*) AS Total_Orders,sum(SaleTotal) AS SaleTotal                           
FROM Customer C,SalesOrderHeader SH WHERE C.CustomerID=SH.CustomerID
group by;
```